# Get image in VueJS?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

In components I have Admin.vue and I call image using

```
<img :src="imageuser">
```

Here components Admin.vue I call script export default

```
export default{
    data(){
        return{
            lists:{},
            imageuser:"",
        }
    },
    mounted(){
        axios.post('admin/getDataAdmin',this.$data)
             .then((response)=> this.lists = response.data)
             .then((response)=>this.imageuser="source/admin/assets/img/"+response.data.image)
             .catch((error)=> this.errors = error.response.data.errors);
    },
```

I can get data in database to array `lists`, but in imageuser I get `imageuser:""`. When I `console.log(response.data.image)` I get error `Cannot read property 'data' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

Your first handler is returning the `data` already:

```js
axios.post('admin/getDataAdmin',this.$data)
     .then((response)=> this.lists = response.data) // this returns `response.data`
     .then((response)=> // so, at this point, the argument is `response.data`
          this.imageuser="source/admin/assets/img/"+response.data.image
     )
```

Do:

```js
axios.post('admin/getDataAdmin',this.$data)
     .then((response)=> this.lists = response.data)
     .then((data)=>this.imageuser="source/admin/assets/img/"+data.image)
//          ^^^^ --- changed                      changed ---^^^^
```

But, from your error, the `response.data` is being `undefined`.

Comment: Thank you, but when I console.log(data) i can get array,  but when i change console.log(data.image),  i can't get data and i get undifinded @@

Comment: Can you past what `console.log` prints? Maybe you could try: `data[0].image`.

Comment: Yup, Thank you :))), I can get value if i using data[0].image but how i get all data in for @@ i have `<tr v-for="item,key in lists">`, i change data[key].image but error :(. Thanks